# Как сделать переменную доступной только для чтения

Tags: классы, методы, переменные, processing

Мне необходимо сделать переменную которую могут изменять **ТОЛЬКО** методы класса, а всем остальным её можно только читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int field;
public int getField() { return field; }
```